# total of all dividend payments for a particular company

Tags: stocks, dividends, stock-dividend

According to http://www.dividend.com/dividend-stocks/financial/asset-management/pfg-principal-financial-group/ on June 26, 2015, PFG paid out $0.38 per share. According to https://www.google.com/finance?q=PFG&ei=BBivVdGJAsbSeL6govgP there are 294.39 million shares of PFG stock. 0.38 * 294,000,000 yields $111 million. So does that mean that PFG paid out $111 million dollars in dividends for the second quarter of 2015?

Comment: Were you surprised by the number?

Answer (score 1):

No - there are additional factors involved.

Note that the shares on issue of a company can change for various reasons (such as conversion/redemption of convertible securities, vesting of restricted employee shares, conversion of employee options, employee stock purchase programs, share placements, buybacks, mergers, rights issues etc.) so it is always worthwhile checking SEC announcements for the company if you want an exact figure.  There may also be multiple classes of shares and preferred securities that have different levels of dividends present.

For PFG, they filed a 10Q on 22 April 2015 and noted they had 294,385,885 shares outstanding of their common stock.  They also noted for the three months ended March 31 2014 that dividends were paid to both common stockholders and preferred stockholders and that there were Series A preferred stock (3 million) and Series B preferred stock (10 million), plus a statement:

> In February 2015, our Board of Directors authorized a share repurchase program of up to $150.0 million of our outstanding common stock. Shares repurchased under these programs are accounted for as treasury stock, carried at cost and reflected as a reduction to stockholders’ equity.

Therefore the exact amount of dividend paid out will not be known until the next quarterly report which will state the exact amount of dividend paid out to common and preferred shareholders for the quarter.